# Mysql sort, giving priority to underscore

Tags: mysql, sorting

I have this field in MySQL. (Varchar)
Which stores product codes. There are like:

```
ABC
ABCG
ABC_K
```

When I used order by on this field ASC, I get the above result.

What I need to give more priority to underscore. So that the result become like this:

```
ABC
ABC_K
ABCG
```

Because ABC_K is more relevant to ABC than ABCG.

Is it possible with MySQL or should I bother with PHP sorting?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
ORDER BY REPLACE(prm, '_', ' '), prm
```

Space characters sort before letters, so this will give them priority.

Answer (score 1):

try

> select prm from tablename order by replace(prm,"_","a") asc;

you can get what's you want. have a try.